# Read txt file from standard input and store whole text into char array

Tags: c

Let me describe what I am trying to do.

1. Compile the source and run with an input text file

   gcc main.c -o main

   ./main < text.txt
2. Then the text inside 'text.txt' should be stored into one single variable. I am not sure, but I think this should be as char array.
3. Ultimately, I want loop through each character of 'text.txt' with its index; in python it should be like as follows

```
    i = 0
    
    while i < len(string):
    
        print(string[i])
    
        if (~~~):
    
            i -= 10(or some other numbers)
    
        else:
    
            i += 1
```

Several points to consider

1. *i* can be decremented and print again from the i-10th character.
2. The program doesn't know the length of the input text file.
3. I cannot specify file directory in the source; the input text must come through standard input in the terminal.

How can I write this in C?

The following was my try in C, didn't work though.

```
int main(){
    char A;
    short i;

    scanf("%s", A);
    printf("%s", A);
    for (i=0; i < strlen(A); i++) {
        printf("%c", A[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried that hasn't worked? There are countless ways to accomplish this in C.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I appended it!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it multiple ways, lets start by getting proper length of file.

```
FILE *f = fopen("textfile.txt", "rb");
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END); // goes to the end of file
long fsize = ftell(f); // tells what position in bytes is 
fclose (f)

f = fopen("textfile.txt", "r");
```

You noticed that I am using `rb` or read binary. thats because to get over the fact that if you use `fseek()` and `ftell()` in non binary mode you are getting into undefined behavior and results may differ between Windows machine and (*)nix machine.

Now how to read a text file into the string. There are multiple ways

1. using `getc()` not preferred
2. using `fscanf()` not preferred either, better than `getc()` in a way that it reads mutiple bytes at the time
3. using `fgets()` you can specify the size of the file you read thus avoiding buffer overflow.

Above is quick and dirty way of reading, without knowing what is your DE like (what OS, compiler etc) I could go into more details how to do it, but tnx to @Nail here is an [article](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/FIO19-C.+Do+not+use+fseek%28%29+and+ftell%28%29+to+compute+the+size+of+a+regular+file), you can read. You could use it and have flags for different OSs instead of using my method.

Comment: Code's approach is reasonable yet "A binary stream need not meaningfully support fseek calls with a whence value of SEEK_END..".  I see no advantage in opening the file in different modes.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I respect your comments, but doesn't windows read wrong file size if you do not open it as binary? Also if you leave it as binary and he decides to use some functions it might read property. Have to go now but will be back in couple of hours to finish this :) TBH, have not played w this in a while.

Comment: The overall goal is not to find the file size, but to store the text into one single variable. Reading text in windows compresses the file's `"\r\n"` into `"\n"` so a lessor file "size" could be used to store the text in a _string_ if done in text mode.  If done in binary mode, might as well read in binary mode too. - say via `fread()`.  IAC, a `rewind()` can then be used rather than the `fclose()/fopen()`.

Comment: [cmu](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/FIO19-C.+Do+not+use+fseek%28%29+and+ftell%28%29+to+compute+the+size+of+a+regular+file) indicates that it is unlikely that this will cause a problem, but still probably bad practice.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, tnx for your comment now I understand what you mean, but didn't that use to cause segfaults on Windows? I am more developer on Linux, but I remember there was a problem on Windows. Perhaps maybe when you read file from Linux with program on Windows machine? Honestly i do not remeber. Tnx once again for your comments.

Comment: I cannot specify file directory in the source.

Comment: `*f = fopen` drop that `*`

Comment: Grazzi @MarcoBonelli